# K3s Flannel interface blocks traffic by overriding routing table entries

Tags: raspberry-pi4, flannel, k3s

I'm installing a [`k3s`](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/) agent on a Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10) and I face the following problem:

**When I start the k3s agent all the network traffic is blocked because `flannel` adds overriding entries to the routing table (with lower metric)**

Here are my network interfaces and routing table *before* starting `k3s`:

```sh
$ ip a
1: lo: [...]
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:3c:cb:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:3c:cb:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.7/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4cd2:3438:9850:12/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip ro
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.11.7 metric 303
192.168.11.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.11.7 metric 303
```

Here are the interfaces and routing table when `k3s` is running:

```sh
$ k3s agent --flannel-iface wlan
[...]
$ ip a
1: lo: [...]
2: eth0: [...] 
3: wlan0: [...]
15: flannel.1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/ether 3e:67:43:a9:0a:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.4.0/32 scope global flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.11.7/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global noprefixroute flannel.1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cef8:2a6c:6b05:da4b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip ro
default via 192.168.11.1 dev flannel.1 src 192.168.11.7 metric 214
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.11.7 metric 303
10.42.0.0/24 via 10.42.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.42.2.0/24 via 10.42.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
192.168.11.0/24 dev flannel.1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.11.7 metric 214
192.168.11.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.11.7 metric 303
```

=> Why are the routes for the local non-virtual network `192.168.0.0/24` created? How can I disable the creation of these routes? Am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I almost self-answered my question: lower the metric of `wlan0` fixes the issue.

By default on Raspberry the routes associated to the `wlan` interfaces have a higher metric because [they're considered as a less stable link than wired](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98074/static-ip-issues-for-wlan0-and-eth0#98079) `eth0` interfaces

Fix:

```
# In /etc/dhcpcd.conf:
[...]
iface wlan0
[...]
metric 42
```

Et voilà!